# How to get object from model?

Tags: java, html, controller, thymeleaf, crud

First of all sry for my english.
I create a CRUD project in which you can create users and games. Users have money for which you can buy the game and add to your library. In the process, I ran into a problem. I can not get the object from the model in the controller. What could be the problem?

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/user-profile/{id}")
public String getUserProfile(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model) {
    logger.debug("Received user data");
    model.addAttribute("user", userDAO.findOne(id));
    model.addAttribute("gameLib", userDAO.findOne(id).getGames());
    return "user/userProfile";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/order-list")
public String getOrderGameList(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
    logger.debug("Received order list for user");
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    model.addAttribute("games", gameDAO.findAll());
    return "order/order-form";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/order-list/{gameId}")
public String postOrderGameList(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, @PathVariable Integer gameId) {
    logger.debug("Add game in user library");
    Game game = gameDAO.findOne(gameId);
    logger.debug("Ordering game");
    user.setWallet(user.getWallet() - game.getPrice());
    user.getGames().add(game);
    if (user.getWallet() < game.getPrice()) {
        logger.debug("Ordering failed");
    } else {
        logger.debug("Ordering game");
        user.setWallet(user.getWallet() - game.getPrice());
        user.getGames().add(game);
    }
    return "redirect:/user-profile/{" + user.getId() + "}";
}
```

HTML

```
<h2>Games</h2>
<table class="list">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="game : ${games}">
        <td th:text="${game.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${game.name}">Game</td>
        <td th:text="${game.description}">Description</td>
        <td th:text="${game.gameType}">type</td>
        <td th:text="${game.year}">2017</td>
        <td th:text="${game.price}">0</td>
        <td>
            <form th:action="@{/users/order-list/} + ${game.id}" method="post">
                <input type="submit" th:value="Buy"/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is [link](https://github.com/EricShooter/GameLibraryProject) to full project

**UPD**

[App VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKgPF.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that need work.

You need to tell Thymeleaf about your model attribute object and ideally how it should bind to it.  Add `th:object` to the form tag and `th:field` to the input tag.  I'm also suspecting that you'll want a `@PostMapping` for the logic in your last method.

**Aside:** 
`@RequestMapping(value = "/order-list")` can be shortened to
`@RequestMapping("/order-list")` since there's only one value in the list.  I'm also assuming that you do relevant checks for NPEs throughout that code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was sure there was an error in the wording of the page code. I do not know how to write it correctly so that it works on the principle of push-buy. Above, I added a picture of how this should work. Can you tell me how to formulate the code correctly?

Comment: Have a look through http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form